# Merge two PSCustomObjects into one- PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need help in PowerShell to combine two outputs or two PSCustomObjects into One.
For example,

```
$services = Get-Service | Select Name, Starttype,Status
$processes = Get-Process | Select ID
```

I need the output with the table headers
**Name, Starttype, Status, ID**

I have already tried creating CSV and joining them but the problem is Process ID starts when the entire output ends for the services. I need them to a parallel.

Second I have tried to create PSCustomObjects but no luck.

Please help me with the PowerShell code.

Actual code that I'm trying to achieve.

```
**$exclusionItems = @()
$OasHighItems = @()   
foreach($item in $items){
    $exclusionItems  += [PSCustomObject]@{
        EXCLUSION_BY_NAME_OR_LOCATION = $item.EXCLUSION_BY_NAME_OR_LOCATION
        EXCLUSION_EXCLUDE_SUBFOLDERS = $item.EXCLUSION_EXCLUDE_SUBFOLDERS
        EXCLUSION_ON_READ= $item.EXCLUSION_ON_READ
    }
    
}
foreach($oas in $oashigh){
    $oashighItems += [PSCustomObject]@{
        OAS_PROCESSES_LIST = $oas
    }
}
$Array = @()
$Array = $exclusionItems,$oashighItems
$Array | Update-FirstObjectProperties | Export-Excel $ExcelParams -TableName Table -Show**
```

Comment: how are you associating the items in `Get-Service` with the items in `Get-Process`?

Comment: It is just an example, I have few XML files and each file output has different PSCustomObject outputs. For example, the First output has three headings, and the second has one. I need to combine them into one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining Multiple CSV Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752072/combining-multiple-csv-files) or [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026) or [Powershell. Combine properties of objects in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64805051/powershell-combine-properties-of-objects-in-array)

Comment: @Chirag, if the linked posts do not solve your problem, please update your question with representative sample input and expected output.

Comment: @Chirag - then you 1st need to decide how to associate any given item in the 1st collection with any given item in the 2nd collection. you also need to provide a realistic set of input data AND how you want the output data to look.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to join the two objects by their names, i.e. match the Process-Name with the Service-Name. For this you can loop over all processes & services, keep only those where service-name equals process-name, and use a  calculated property to merge the result into one object:

```
$services = Get-Service;
Get-Process | ForEach-Object {$p = $_;  $services |
                Where-Object{$p.ProcessName -eq $_.Name} |
                    Select-Object Name,StartType,Status,@{n='ID';e={$p.ID}}}
```

The output on my machine is:

```
Name                  StartType  Status    ID
----                  ---------  ------    --
CcmExec               Automatic Running 14856
CmRcService           Automatic Running  5748
FusionInventory-Agent Automatic Running  5996
IBMPMSVC              Automatic Running  3540
IntelAudioService     Automatic Running  6104
... and so on ...
```